# Dropbox and Ubuntu Software Center doesn't work after setting python3.4 as default

Tags: 14.04, software-center, dropbox, python3

In Ubuntu 14.04, I've set `python3.4` as the default `python` version. After that, Dropbox doesn't launch at startup and the Ubuntu Software Center cannot open up anymore. Running them from the command line, I have:

```
petrux@MYMACHINE:~$ dropbox 
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 232
    except OSError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

petrux@orion:~$ software-center
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 140
    print time.time()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I work around this problem?

EDIT: I just noticed that, in addition, there is no audio output any more.

Comment: We need log, try to launch dropbox from terminal with dropbox and give us the log.

Comment: @AgentCool I edited the question adding the dumps. I'm pretty sure they're python version related issues. Thanks.

Comment: This is due to switching Python version only. If you dont use python3 then switch it to Python2 else tell us purpose of switching to python3 . so we will try to help

Comment: I want to switch to python3 as I'm using a library which is avialable only for python3.

Comment: You still have a choice , for example its a python script/program and need python3 environment then by using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` you can set like your program have to use python3 environment. and you can keep 2.7 as default environment of yours

Answer (score 6):

If this is the problem you are getting.

```
File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 215
    except OSError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It may be due to update of your python from python2 to python3 and setting python3 as default python. to get rid of of this problem you can follow the below steps.

Tyr the below steps,

1. Open `cd /usr/bin/dropbox` file and in the edit mode.
2. Change the first line from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2`
3. Restart the dropbox app and it should work good.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

The generic command `python` and shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` currently map to Python 2. Do NOT change that mapping yourself - it will break many essential system applications and services in 14.04 that still use Python 2, and won't work with Python 3 yet.

Undo whatever you did to set Python 3.4 as the default python version.

Both Python 2 and Python 3 are included with 14.04. Applications and services on your system may rely on either.

To launch the Python 3 interpreter, use the command `python3` or put a shebang  `#!/usr/bin/python3` in your script.

To launch the Python 2 interpreter, use the command `python` or `python2`, or put the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python2` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I set default python to 3 using the following command
`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

changing it back to python 2 solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `update-alternatives` already configured, a good practice would be list all python installations in order to switch between them quickly

First add all python versions installed (can be seen executing `ls /usr/bin/python*`) with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python <path-to-python-version> <priority>
```

Example (to solve this problem with Dropbox, add python 2.7 to be listed on the alternatives)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 3
```

Execute `sudo update-alternatives --config python` to list all added alternatives and choose python version typing the respective Selection value.